# What is the shortest way to compute $\int \sqrt{x-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I can solve this problem after $\int \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x} \text{dx}$ by substitution $x=u^2$ and then $u=\sin v$, and at last I get $\int \cos^4 x$.
But it looks a very long way, is there any shortest approach?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308440/how-is-this-integral-solved, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287238/integration-by-parts-int-sqrtx-x2-dx/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x-x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2},$$ so a single substitution of the form $$2x - 1 = \sin \theta, \quad dx = \frac{1}{2} \cos \theta \, d\theta$$ immediately yields $$\int \sqrt{x-x^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{4}\int \cos^2 \theta \, d\theta,$$ and the rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 9):

This may not be what you want, but the shortest way is definite by geometric intuition. The integrand is nothing but a semicircle centered at $(0.5, 0.0)$ with radius $0.5$.

So the integration, or the area, is $1/2 \cdot \pi (1/2)^2 = \pi/8$.[image: semicircle]

Comment: It's beautiful! Of course after $x-x^2=1/4-(x-1/2)^2$

Comment: @NNN, that's what math is!

Comment: Yes, it's beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By rewriting

$$\int \sqrt{x-x^2}dx=\int\sqrt{\frac14-\left(x-\frac12\right)^2}dx$$

Then use the substitution $$x-\frac12=\frac12\sin t$$

Comment: Oh, yes! that's great.